# What is the maximum size to operate with a matrix in Dymola/Modelica?

Tags: matrix, dimensions, modelica, dymola

I would like to know if there's a limit or a maximum for the dimension of a matrix for each known and possible operation we could use on Dymola(Modelica)?

And if it exist to what extent this limit could decrease due to other Operations? And is the value the same for example for Open Modelica?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a limit prescribed by the Modelica language.  For Dymola as the simulation tool I don't think there is "fixed limit" either but there would be a "practical limit".  The practical limit would be related to the size of the executable and the memory requirements both to create the executable and to run and store results from the executable (although there are mechanisms to control the result file size).  For example the following model:

```
model MyModel
  parameter Integer n = 1000;
  Real x[n,n];

equation 
  x = if time < 0.5 then fill(time,n,n) else fill(time*2,n,n);

end MyModel;
```

which has 1000000 variables and equations compiles and simulates but it takes much much longer than the equivalent model where n = 10 (100 variables).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at https://github.com/casella/ScalableTestSuite and http://dx.doi.org/10.3384/ecp15118459 which is looking into scalability problems.